# Failing injection SubjectRepository to DataService in gradle multiproject [spring data]

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have issue with injecting repository to service.
It's my first project in spring.
I made a tutorial from this site:
http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/10/27/using-mysql-in-spring-boot-via-spring-data-jpa-and-hibernate/
and i don't know what is wrong. I try annotation @EnableJpaRepositories, @Repository in interface but didn't help me.
All code is on my github: https://github.com/kklimczak/OpenStudies

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [pl.konradklimczak.openstudies.data.Subject.SubjectRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Transactional
@Repository

use this two annotation in your SubjectRepository from

> import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository; import
>   org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

Comment: add to springboot main class annotations "@EntityScan" and @EnableJpaRepositories resolve my error! :) Thanks :)

Comment: @ kklimczak Use this annotation in yours spring-boot main class  and basepackage is yours project base package
"@SpringBootApplication"
"@ComponentScan(basePackages = "project base package")"
@EntityScan(basePackages ="project base package")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "project base package")